# Encrypting file in C# and decrypt file in Android programming with aes algorithm

Tags: c#, java, android

i wana to encrypt a file in c# and Decrypt the c# encrypted file by java code in my android app ,i know that the best algo is AES256 for do it , my code in android is work correctly (Encrypt and Decrypt) but i can't decrypt the C# result file by my android app , i use following code (Thanks a lot):

functions for encrypt and Decrypt(android):

Encrypt:

```
static void Encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        try {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/logo.png");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Encrypted");


            SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
                    "12345678901234567890123456789012".getBytes(), "AES");

            tv.setText(aeskeySpec.getEncoded().toString());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

            int b;

            byte[] d = new byte[8];
            while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
                cos.write(d, 0, b);

            }

            cos.flush();
            cos.close();
            fis.close();

        }// try
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            tv.setText("Error :" + e.getMessage()); } }// encrypt
```

`static void Decrypt() throws IOException, InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/Encrypted");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        long length = file.length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;

        bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);

        byte[] N = new byte[(int) length - offset];

        int g, s = 0;

        for (g = offset; g < length; g++) {
            N[s++] = bytes[g];
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Decrypted");

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(
                "12345678901234567890123456789012".getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);

        byte[] b = cipher.update(N);


        int j = 0;
        while (j < b.length) {

            fos.write(b[j]);
            j++;
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }`

i use this code for Encrypt in c# :

`public void Encrypt(string FIStr, string FOStr, string PassKey)
        {

            FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(FIStr,
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read);

            FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(FOStr,
               FileMode.Create,
               FileAccess.Write);


            AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bytes=encoding.GetBytes(PassKey);

            AES.Key = bytes;

            ICryptoTransform aesencrypt = AES.CreateEncryptor();

            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,
               aesencrypt,
               CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
            fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Close();
            fsInput.Close();
            fsEncrypted.Close();}`

this code is encypt my files but i can't decrypt this file by my android app :( , plz help me , thanks for all .

Comment: Why are you using cipher.update() instead of cipher.doFinal()?

Comment: in first time i using cipher.dofinal() but not worked so i use cipher.update()

Comment: sorry Joachim Isaksson i test your advise ,right , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ideas for you:

1) Encrypt a simple string such as "hello" using your c# code, then take it to the site http://www.everpassword.com/aes-encryptor and see if it will decrypt it successfully - if so you can verify that your encryption code is working great. Same goes for your Android code - go to the same site I mentioned, encrypt something simple like "hey you", pass the encrypted string through your android code and see if it will decrypt it successfully.

2) Just glancing through your code I noticed the argument to Cipher.getInstance() looks a little bare compared to the android documentation for Cipher.getInstance() - http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html - notice the example argument at the top of the documentation. It specifies parameters in addition to the "AES" that you provide, such as the mode and padding. Are you sure the default mode and padding in android match that of your C# encryption? just a thought.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your ideas, i think my problem is cipher modes between C# and android , i try to solve that , thanks